# How to get userID from snapshot ? (Realtime Database)

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

what i want to do is getting the userID from snapshot and put it in a route argument to navigate to a user page and get all of user data from Realtime database, so far here is what i have done:

- but it didn't work and for sure it has returned a null error.
- You can find a comment below before each snapshot which i need to get the id from in home.dart and user_detail.dart

home.dart

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
    import 'package:idevice_me/providers/project_provider.dart';
    import 'package:idevice_me/screens/user_detail_screen.dart';
    import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
    
    
    
    class HomeWidget extends StatefulWidget {
      const HomeWidget({ Key? key }) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      State<HomeWidget> createState() => _HomeWidgetState();
    }
    
    class _HomeWidgetState extends State<HomeWidget> {
    
      var _isInit = true;
      
      @override
      void didChangeDependencies(){
        if(_isInit){
           Provider.of<ProjectProvider>(context, listen: false).readData();
        }
        _isInit = false;
        super.didChangeDependencies();
      }
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return StreamBuilder(
          stream: Provider.of<ProjectProvider>(context, listen: false).readData(),
          builder: (ctx, AsyncSnapshot snapshot){
            if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting){
                    return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                  }
            if(snapshot.hasData){
    //--------------------
    //This is the snapshot
    //--------------------
             final userSnapshot = snapshot.data!.snapshot.children.toList();
             
              return Column(
                children: [
                 const SizedBox(height: 20,),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 15.0, left: 15.0),
                    child: TextFormField(
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                labelText: 'Search',
                                labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 14,color: Colors.grey.shade400,fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                                enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey.shade300),
                                ),
                                focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                                  borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.blue),
                                ),
                                floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.auto,
                              ),
                              key: const ValueKey('search'),
                                validator: (value){
                                  if(value!.isEmpty || value.length < 2){
                                    return 'Please enter at least 2 characters';
                                  }
                                  return null;
                                },
                                keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                                onSaved: (value){
                                 // _userName = value!;
                                },
                               
                            ),
                  ),
                         const SizedBox(height: 20,),
                  Expanded(
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: userSnapshot.length,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctx, i)=> Column(
                        children: [
                          // ignore: sized_box_for_whitespace
                          GestureDetector(
                            onTap: (){
                              Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(
                                UserDetailScreen.routeName, 

    //------------------------------------------------------
    //Here is the argument which should take the snapshot id
    //------------------------------------------------------
    
                                arguments: userSnapshot[i].toString(), //convert it toString() because it's coming from a List
                                );
                            },
                            child: Container(
                              height: 160,
                              width: 350,
                              child: Card(
                                elevation: 5,
                                shape:RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
                                child: Column(
                                  children: [
                                    const SizedBox(height: 20,),
                                    Padding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 20.0, left: 20.0),
                                      child: Row(
                                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                        children: [
                                          const Text('Name:', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),),
                                          Text(
                                            userSnapshot[i].child('username').value, 
                                            style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                                            ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ),const SizedBox(height: 10,),
                                    Padding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 20.0, left: 20.0),
                                      child: Row(
                                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                        children: [
                                          const Text('Email:', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),),
                                          Text(
                                          userSnapshot[i].child('email').value,
                                          style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    const SizedBox(height: 10,),
                                    Padding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 20.0, left: 20.0),
                                      child: Row(
                                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                        children: [
                                          const Text('Date:', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),),
                                          Text(
                                          userSnapshot[i].child('dateTime').value.toString(),
                                          style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    const SizedBox(height: 10,),
                                    Padding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 20.0, left: 20.0),
                                      child: Row(
                                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                        children: [
                                          const Text('Phone:', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),),
                                          Text(
                                          userSnapshot[i].child('phone').value.toString(),
                                          style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      )
                      ),
                  ),
                ],
              );
            }
            return const Center(child: Text('There is something wrong!'),);
          },
          );
      }
    }
```

user_detail.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:idevice_me/widgets/user_detail_widget.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';

class UserDetailScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  static const routeName = 'user-screen';
  const UserDetailScreen({ Key? key }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
//------------------------
//Extracted snapshot here
//------------------------
    final userID = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as String;
    return Scaffold(
      key: scaffoldKey,
      body: Column( 
        children: [
          const SizedBox(height: 30,),
          Row( 
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
                  IconButton(
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.notes_outlined,), 
                  onPressed: ()=> scaffoldKey.currentState!.openDrawer(),
                  ), 

                 const Text(
                  'i-Device',
                   style: TextStyle(fontSize: 23),
                   ),

                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 10.0),
                    // ignore: sized_box_for_whitespace
                    child: Container(
                      height: 40,
                      width: 40,
                      child: const Icon(Icons.home)
                 
            ),
                  ),
                  
            ],
          
          ),
         
            Expanded(
             child: StreamBuilder(
//--------------------------------
//used snapshot here as the userID
//--------------------------------
               stream: FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref().child('users').child(userID).onValue,
               builder: (ctx, AsyncSnapshot snapshot){
                 if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting){
                   return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);
                 }

                 if(snapshot.hasData){
                   final userData = snapshot.data.snapshot.value;
                   return Column(
                     children: [
                       const SizedBox(height: 20,),
                      Text(userData['username']),
                     ],
                   );
                 }
                 return const Center(child: Text('Something went wrong!'),);
               }
               ),
             ),
        ],
      ),
     
    );
  }
}
```

So how can i get the userID from snapshot and trigger it into argument to navigate to user detail page?

Answer (score 2):

You should create a model containing all your person information and when you get data from firebase you should convert it from json format to model format. After setting all the variables in the detail model and adding all the data, you must give the parameter to the page you want to show the person detail.

> Here is example model

```
  class UserModel {
  String uid;
  String email;
  String name;
  String surname;
  String pathOfPhoto;
  String phoneNumber;

  UserModel(
    this.uid,
    this.email,
    this.name,
    this.surname,{
    this.pathOfPhoto,
    this.phoneNumber,
  });

  UserModel.fromMap(Map snapshot)
      : uid = snapshot['uid'] ?? '',
        email = snapshot['email'] ?? '',
        name = snapshot['name'] ?? '',
        surname = snapshot['surname'] ?? '',
        pathOfPhoto = snapshot['pathOfPhoto'] ?? '',
        phoneNumber = snapshot['phoneNumber'] ?? '';

  toJson() {
    return {
      "uid": uid,
      "email": email,
      "name": name,
      "surname": surname,
      "pathOfPhoto": pathOfPhoto,
      "phoneNumber": phoneNumber,
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: The same thing i'm already doing that in the state management Provider. if you need to navigate to a specific user uid and get all of that user data which you did in the model you need the snapshot id it self! :(, actually with firestore it works and what you could do is simple here it is: userSnapshot[i].id, but with Realtime database it doesn't work like that :'(

Comment: Solved by a simple way Alhamdulilah, here is the solution: userSnapshot[i].key.toString()